# How to redirect to previous page after successful register in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

Right now `redirectTo` is set to `/home`.

I want to know how I can redirect to the previous page.

I tried using

```
protected $redirectTo = URL::previous();
```

but I get parse error, expecting `','' or` ';''

What would be the best solution to approach this problem? I assume I'd need to over-ride the `$redirectTo` variable somehow with `URL::previous()` and that would be sufficient.

This is my register controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use URL;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        // 'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        // 'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: The previous page in the case should be the register form page.

Comment: Are they getting sent to the register form because they've clicked a register link or because of some auth middleware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RegisterController` uses the `RegistersUsers` trait. When you submit the form, the `register()` method of this trait is called. It validates the input, creates and authenticates the user and then redirects to the path specified by the `redirectPath()` method. This method is actually set in the `RedirectsUsers` trait, which is used by the `RegistersUsers` trait.

The `redirectPath()` method will look for a `redirectTo()` method on the controller. If it does find this method, it will use whatever is returned from it. If doesn't find this method, it will redirect to the url specified in the `redirectTo` property instead.

So, if you need to set the redirect path dynamically, put this in your RegisterController:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return url()->previous();
}
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#included-authenticating).

Comment: perfect explanation as well

Answer (score 2):

add this to `RegisterController`:

```
protected function redirectTo(){
    return url()->previous();
}
```

Note: if present the field `$redirectTo` , remove it

Answer (score 2):

This is much better if the user is coming from the login page to the register page and we need to redirect him after registration to the previous link:

add this to RegisterController:

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to stay on the same page when no authentication is required and also go on the next one for which is required, it is possible to overwrite the code by adding the following code to the RegisterController.

The first part write the last page that was accessed before displaying the register blade, and the second part redirects to written page upon successful registration.

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    if(!session()->has('url.intended'))
    {
        session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
    }

    return view('auth.register');
}

protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```