# How to keep user in the same page when register? (laravel)

Tags: laravel

The idea I want to keep the user on the same page when he registers and shows his message to wait for active his account.

I tried in **RegisterController**

```
protected $redirectTo = '/register';
```

**But** when I register it redirects me to the home page!

SO How to keep the user in register page and show him the message to waiting to active his 
account.

> I used Auth of Laravel and my version is **5.8**

Thanks

Comment: You can override redirectTo method as your create methods.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the redirect function in the app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'You will receive a confirmation email');

}
```

In register.blade.php

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

**EDIT :**

[How to redirect to previous page after successful register in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326430/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-after-successful-register-in-laravel)

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return url()->previous();
}
```

Comment: Still redirect me to the home page!

Comment: got the answer. update your answer  RegisterController to RegistersUsers
and put the return there

Comment: if you edit the RegistersUsers trait, it is possible that this will no longer work when updating laravel

Comment: So I try your answer but still redirect me to the home page!

Comment: you have to replace protected $redirectTo = '/'; by the function in the edited answer

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that now but the same thing redirects me to the home page!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create `redirectTo` method which laravel will give priority when redirecting your users after registration. Then remove `redirectTo` property, even though method will take precedence.

```
public function redirectTo() {
   return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'message for account activation.');
}
```

Inside the view (register.blade.php), you can have this.

```
@if (session('status'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session('status') }}
   </div>
@endif
```

**EDIT:**
Please ignore the previous answer. It requires custom registration so that you can take control of what happens after registration.

Since you are using Laravel Auth, you can continue and make use of their email verification like so.

1. Change `Auth::routes();` inside routes/web.php to  `Auth::routes(['verify'=>true]);`
2. Add `->middleware('verified);` to the home route. This will prevent user from seeing this page until email is verified. Complete should be like so

   ```
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('verified');
   ```
3. Go to `App\User` and make sure that the model has the following lines in addition to all other lines you have there at the top. Focus here is on `implements MustVerifyEmail`

   ```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

    class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail 
    {
     //rest of the code here
    }
   ```
4. Lastly, make sure that `.env` file has the correct email settings. You can use [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/signin), it's free for testing purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ( Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected )

show this error

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it really helps this time :)